# Search icon in toolbar is not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar, menuitem, searchview

This is the code I used in the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

`@drawable/search` is a white search icon and toolbar background is black. This is my code in MainActivity.class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
 }

 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
    val searchViewItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem) as SearchView

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

}

After doing all these things, the search icon is not visible in the toolbar. But, its clickable. When i click on the right side of toolbar, the searchview opens up. But, the icon is not visible.

Comment: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>` added in manifest?

Comment: added now. but,still not working